# Update shopping cart

Tags: php, cart

I'm pretty new to PHP, just followed a course and working on my final case to get a certificate. We're working on a webstore and I'm having trouble with updating my shopping cart. I know that this question has been asked before, but after reading through the answers, I can't fix my own code. I hope someone can help me with this. 
If there's 1 item in the cart, it updates well, with more items, just one 1 item will be updated. Here's my shopping cart code *(it's been EDITED since first post to be more complete)*:

```
                <FORM method=get name=cart_quantity 
        action=winkelwagen.php>
        <TABLE border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="100%">
          <TBODY>
          <TR>
            <TD>
              <TABLE class=productListing border=0 cellSpacing=0 
              cellPadding=2 width="100%">
                <TBODY>

                <TR>
                  <TD class=infoBoxHeading3 align=middle>Verwijder</TD>
                  <TD class=infoBoxHeading3>Artikel(en)</TD>
                  <TD class=infoBoxHeading3 align=middle>Aantal</TD>
                  <TD class=infoBoxHeading3 
                  align=right>Totaal&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD></TR>

<?php                   
$sqlWinkelwagen = "SELECT * FROM tblorder
    INNER JOIN tblorderregels
    INNER JOIN tblartikelen
    WHERE tblorder.Ordernummer = tblorderregels.Ordernummer AND SessieID = '" . session_id() . "' AND tblorderregels.Artikelnummer = tblartikelen.Artikelnummer";
$rsWinkelwagen = mysqli_query($db, $sqlWinkelwagen);

$WinkelwagenRegel = 0;

while ($rWinkelwagen = mysqli_fetch_array($rsWinkelwagen))
{
?>

                <TR class=productListing-even>
                  <TD class=productListing-data vAlign=top 
                    align=middle><br><br>
                    <a href="winkelwagen.php?Artikelnummer=<?php echo($rWinkelwagen["Artikelnummer"]);?>&action=del"><img border="0" src="images/bin.png" width="30" height="30"></a>
                  <input type=hidden name=Artikelnummer value=<?php echo($rWinkelwagen["Artikelnummer"]);?>>
                  <TD class=productListing-data><BR>
                    <TABLE border=0 cellSpacing=2 cellPadding=2>
                      <TBODY>

                      <TD class=productListing-data align=middle><A 
                          href="http://www.mijnoscommerce.nl/demo/shop1/product_info.php?products_id=35{1}1"><IMG 
                          title=" iPhone 3G - 8GB " border=0 
                          alt="iPhone 3G - 8GB" 
                          src="images/<?php echo($rWinkelwagen["Afbeelding"]);?>" width=100 
                          height=80></A></TD>

                        <TD class=productListing-data vAlign=top><BR><A 
                          href="http://www.mijnoscommerce.nl/demo/shop1/product_info.php?products_id=35{1}1"><B>
                          <?php echo($rWinkelwagen["Artikelnaam"]); ?>
                          </B></A> </TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD>

                  <TD class=productListing-data vAlign=top 
                    align=middle><BR><BR><INPUT 
                    type="text" value=<?php echo($rWinkelwagen["Aantal"]); ?> size=4 
                    name=AantalArtikel[<?php echo($rWinkelwagen["Artikelnummer"]);?>]
                    >
                    <input type=hidden 
                    name=ArtikelID[<?php echo($rWinkelwagen["Artikelnummer"]);?>] 
                    value=<?php echo($rWinkelwagen["Artikelnummer"]);?>
                    >
                    <input type=hidden name=action value=upd></TD>
                  <TD class=productListing-data vAlign=top 
                    align=right><BR><BR><B>Ä 
<?php 
                            $TotaalArtikel = $rWinkelwagen["Aantal"] *         $rWinkelwagen["Prijs"];
                            echo($TotaalArtikel);  
                            $TotaalWinkelwagen = $TotaalWinkelwagen + $TotaalArtikel;
                            ?>
                </B>&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD> 
                <?php 
} //einde while winkelwagen inhoud
mysqli_free_result($rsWinkelwagen);
?>
                </TBODY></TABLE></TD></TR>




          <TR>
            <TD><IMG border=0 alt="" 
              src="winkelwagen_files/pixel_trans.gif" width="100%" 
            height=10></TD></TR>

          <TR>
            <TD class=main align=right><B>Subtotaal: Ä <?php echo($TotaalWinkelwagen); ?> 
            </B>&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD></TR>
          <TR>
            <TD class=stockWarning align=middle><BR>Artikelen met een: *** 
              Zijn momenteel niet besckikbaar in de door u gevraagde 
              hoeveelheid.<BR>U kan de geselecteerde hoeveelheid wel laten 
              staan en bij het afrekenen zal de beschikbare hoeveelheid 
              getoond worden.</TD></TR>
          <TR>
            <TD><IMG border=0 alt="" 
              src="winkelwagen_files/pixel_trans.gif" width="100%" 
            height=10></TD></TR>
          <TR>
            <TD>
              <TABLE class=infoBox2 border=0 cellSpacing=1 cellPadding=2 
              width="100%">
                <TBODY>
                <TR class=infoBoxContents>
                  <TD>
                    <TABLE border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=2 width="100%">

                      <TBODY>
                      <TR>
                        <TD width=10><IMG border=0 alt="" 
                          src="winkelwagen_files/pixel_trans.gif" width=10 
                          height=1></TD>
                        <TD class=main><INPUT title=" Update Winkelwagen " 
                          border=0 alt="Update Winkelwagen" 
                          src="winkelwagen_files/button_update_cart.gif" 
                          type=image
                          ></TD>
                        <TD class=main><A 
                          href="index.php"><IMG 
                          title=" Verder winkelen " border=0 
                          alt="Verder winkelen" 
                          src="winkelwagen_files/button_continue_shopping.gif" 
                          width=129 height=16></A></TD>
                        <TD class=main align=right><A 
                          href="betalingswijze.php"><IMG 
                          title=" Afrekenen " border=0 alt=Afrekenen 
                          src="winkelwagen_files/button_checkout.gif" 
                          width=86 height=16></A></TD>
                        <TD width=10><IMG border=0 alt="" 
                          src="winkelwagen_files/pixel_trans.gif" width=10 
                          height=1></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></FORM>
```

After applying the form it returns to the same page, on top with this code:

```
   <?php 
 require_once 'config.php';

 $db = mysqli_connect($strDatabaseServer, $strUsername, $strPassword, $strDatabase);
 if(!$db)
  die('Fout bij verbinden met database: ' . mysqli_connect_error());

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblorder where SessieId = '" . session_id() . "'";
 if(!$rs = mysqli_query($db, $sql))
 die('Fout in query: ' . mysqli_error());

 if (mysqli_num_rows($rs) > 0)
{
$r = mysqli_fetch_array($rs);
$intOrdernummer = $r["Ordernummer"]; // bestaande ordernr
mysqli_free_result($rs);
}

//echo ($intOrdernummer); 


if (isset($_GET["action"]))
{
switch ($_GET["action"])
{
    case "del":
        $strSQL = "delete from tblorderregels where Artikelnummer = '" . $_GET["Artikelnummer"] . "' AND Ordernummer = $intOrdernummer";
        break;

    case "upd":

        foreach($_GET['ArtikelID'] as $key => $id){

            $Artikelnummer = $id;
            $aantal = $_GET['AantalArtikel'][$key];
            //$sql2 = "update orders SET quantity = '$quantity' where item_id = '$item_id' ";


        $strSQL = "update tblorderregels set Aantal = '" . $aantal . "' where Artikelnummer = '" . $Artikelnummer . "' AND Ordernummer = $intOrdernummer";
        }
        break;
    }

$intGoed = mysqli_query($db, $strSQL);
if (!$intGoed)
    die("Foutje in de SQL: " . $strSQL);
}

?>
```

I tried to make unique variables with GET, but somehow it isn't working
I hope some one can help with this, thanks in advance!

Comment: @MartinBean that's not constructive - the OP is simply asking for help as per the point of the SO.

Comment: The web store isn't going online, it's final case for my study: it's learning material

Comment: @beingalex How’s this for being constructive? Ronnie: _Never_ use variables in a MySQL statement directly. _Always_ sanitise user input data. Your code is currently vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Hi Martin,  Thanks for your input. I'm going to sanitise my input data, thanks for mentioning!

Answer (score 1):

To confirm:

- 4th line of the html is a link that will give GET variables of `$_GET['Artikelnummer'] = Artikelnummer` and `$_GET['action'] = del` if you click the link
- Final line of the html is a hidden input that will give a GET variable (since no method specified in the form element) of `$_POST['action']  = upd`, there is a hidden input for the Artikelnummer, and a text input for the number. You get this if you submit the form (there is no submit button in your current html)

Things that work:

- If single/multiple item(s), clicking the delete link would just delete the one item you clicked for
- If a single item, updating the `name=AantalArtikel` text input with the new number and submitting the form would update that item

Problems:

- If multiple items, there is no way to tell which `name=AantalArtikel` text input refers to which Artikelnummer

Solution:

- A separate form for each product that you want to update so multiple submit buttons
- Or, each `name=AantalArtikel` text input must have a unique name e.g. `name=AantalArtikel-Artikel1`

Tip:

- use `print_r($_GET)` to view what the form/link output is to see where you are going wrong

Additional Comments:

The rough format would be:

```
HTML
form
  hidden input action="upd"
  hidden input name="number_of_items" value="2"
  product1 html
     hidden input name="product1_name" value="red_car"
     text input name="product1_number" value="1"
     link ?product_name=NAME1&action=del
  product2 html
     hidden input name="product2_name" value="blue_car"
     text input name="product2_number" value="1"
     link ?product_name=NAME2&action=del
  submit button

PHP
  if GET action=del
     -> sanitise input, delete product
  if GET action=upd
     -> for (i <= GET number_of_items)
        -> sanitise input, get variables using $i in the name to loop through the numbers
```

Comment: Separate forms for each product is not what I want. 
I read about giving each "name=" a variable ID, but I don't know how to catch these and put them in my mysql update string

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. The mysql query was not in my switch, so that's why the sql query was not being performed well.

Thanks for helping!